# Asynchronous console input froze previous input C

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdin

I want to write simple program with 3 threads (main, reader, writer). Reader thread is something like that:

```
char message[128];
while (1) {
    std::cin >> message;
}
```

Main thread catch `Ctrl+Z` action and then user press this controls, then I want to show simple choice like `Do you want finish? (Y/N) __` where `__` is `std::cin` action. Now I have something like that:

```
void signal_handler(int signal) {
    char finish;
    std::cout << "Do you want finish? (Y/N)";
    std::cin >> finish;
}

int main(void) {
    signal(20, signal_handler);
    ...
```

But when I sent for simple `Y` at first is going to reader thread, now when I sent `Y` is going to main thread. How I can redirect stdin to main thread?

Comment: You're doing way too much in a signal handler, just set a flag that is checked by your program. Also didn't hardcode signal numbers but use the names.

Comment: What is "C" as in "before C"?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry, my fault. I'm very bad in English :< I prefer another languages.

Comment: But what is the meaning of "C" now? If you mean the language, your language here is C++ and also, that should be a tag and not be part of the title.

Answer (score 0):

Standard IO (which `std::cin` wraps) is not thread aware.

It is the responsibility of your multi-threaded application to handle it's resources in a sensible way.

One way to do that is to have a single thread responsible for reading STDIN and pushing to a memory queue that is controlled by some multi-threaded aware abstraction code. Then have that resource "locked" to the required thread as required by your program logic.